# Unexpected behavior when printing back MIPS input variables

Tags: debugging, assembly, mips

I am using `spim` to test MIPS bit manipulation. The program starts by taking in two variables and printing them back out to the user to make sure they were stored correctly. Here's the code:

```
# Ask the user for two inputs, then calculate the value of 16*(x-y)+8
# First, subtract y from x
# Next, multiply both by 16 by left-shifting them four times.
# Finally, add eight to this value and output the result.

.data
    debug: .asciiz "DEBUG: \n"

.data
    newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
    main:
        # Capture first input, place in $t0
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0

        # Capture the second input, place in $t1
        syscall
        move $t1, $v0

        # DEBUG: Print $t0
        li $v0 4
        la $a0 debug
        syscall

        li $v0 1
        move $a0, $t0
        syscall

        li $v0 4
        la $a0 newline
        syscall

        # DEBUG: Print $t1
        li $v0 4
        la $a0 debug
        syscall

        li $v0 1
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall

        li $v0 4
        la $a0 newline
        syscall
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

This code has unpredictable behavior: when the first number input is `5` it correctly responds with `5`, but inputting `2` makes it print `0.00000000` and not allow another input, `7` makes it ignore the second number, and `8` results in a `memory address out of bounds` message.

That makes it seem like the problem is size: maybe MIPS stores these inputs in only three bits? Introducing a read float or read double only makes MIPS ignore the input completely, though.

What's missing?

Comment: What syscall are you calling in second?

Comment: The same one, because $v0 is still set to 5.

Comment: But you copy $v0 into $t0 just before, surely that's a weird way of setting $t0 to 5.

Comment: @Collisteru: Check the documentation for `syscall` 5. It returns in `$v0` the number read. Therefore if you dont load again the value before the next syscall you will use whatever number is read in the first syscall.